# Higher Order functions in Spark SQL query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I just got introduced to Spark SQL higher order functions `transform(), filter()`  etc. I searched online, but couldn't find much advanced use-cases leveraging these functions.

Can anyone please explain `transform()` with a couple of advanced real-life use-case using sql query. Does it always need to work on nested complex types (arrays, struct etc) ? Or can it be used to process simple data-type records as well ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following online resource vividly demonstrates in %sql mode :

https://docs.databricks.com/delta/data-transformation/higher-order-lambda-functions.html